# Qual é a diferença entre stopPropagation e stopImmediatePropagation?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Eu percebi a um tempo atrás, que era possível usar essas duas funções, mas qual seria a diferença entre elas?

Qual é a diferença entre `event.stopPropagation()`  e `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` no Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

`stopPropagation()` vai prevenir os `handlers` dos **elementos pais** de dispararem.

Já o `stopImmediatePropagation()`, previne os `handlers` dos **elementos pais**, e também previne **qualquer outro handler do mesmo elemento** de disparar.
Exemplo rápido da [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/):

```
$( "p" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$( "p" ).click(function( event ) {
  // Esse aqui não vai executar, por causa do stopImmediatePropagation no handler anterior
  $( this ).css( "background-color", "#f00" );
});
```